# Is it possible to have one web role with multiple domains and SSL certificates on windows azure?

Tags: ssl, azure, role

Is it possible to have one web role hosted on Windows Azure which respond to multiple domains (to be precise 10 -> ex. www.company.com, www.company.de, www.company.co.uk … ect. ) and having both HTTP and HTTPS (SSL certificates) ?

If this is not possible, what is the alternatives to run one web role with multiple domains and having SSL on them with windows azure ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "Full IIS" WebRole.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2010/12/02/new-full-iis-capabilities-differences-from-hosted-web-core.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Yes, now you can do it using "SSL hostheaders" with a new supported feature called SNI, available in IIS 8 (Windows Server 2012).

So, you will need to:

1. Map all your domains to a single cloudapp.net subdomain using CNAME
2. Automate the SSL certificate installation
3. Automate the HTTPS binding creation in IIS with SSL SNI hostheaders

I'm a Microsoft Technical Evangelist and I have posted a detailed explanation and a sample "plug & play" source-code at:
http://www.vic.ms/microsoft/windows-azure/multiples-ssl-certificates-on-windows-azure-cloud-services/

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to present the same web site to all these domains, you should be OK with HTTP connections - just set each one up as a CNAME to the Azure web endpoint.  I guess HTTPS is a bit trickier, but [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazure/thread/bcf410ba-3dcd-463a-919d-c3e175b19aaf) indicates you will need a "multi domain certificate" (see Google).  I have not tried it, but presumably this certificate can be [uploaded to Azure in the usual way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff795779.aspx).  I have just noticed that your question appears to be a duplicate of of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461260/azure-web-role-multiple-ssl-certs-pointing-to-a-single-endpoint). I am also adding my answer there.